# PHP: How to convert date+time in string format to format suitable for sorting data?

Tags: php, string, date, time

I am loading articles from RSS and there is the date value formatted in various  as:

```
January 4, 2013
Fri, 04 Jan 2013 13:18:05 +0000
Fri, 04 Jan 2013 07:33:51 EST
Jan 4, 2013
Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:27:46 GMT
```

Is there any uniform way, how to save these values into the database column with datatype `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or `TIME`, which is the most appropriate for sorting these articles?

Comment: Wow. 2k reputation and not a glance to the right column

Comment: you can try bruteforcing by simply running those values through `strtotime()` in php, which gives you a unix timestamp, which you can then stuff into mysql with `from_unixtime($php_timestamp)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this-

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("January 4, 2013"));  //  2013-01-04 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Fri, 04 Jan 2013 13:18:05 +0000"));  //2013-01-04 13:18:05
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Fri, 04 Jan 2013 07:33:51 EST"));    //2013-01-04 12:33:51
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Jan 4, 2013"));  //2013-01-04 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Fri, 04 Jan 2013 02:27:46 GMT"));    //2013-01-04 02:27:46
```

updated datetime format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtotime` function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dateString));
```